# How to open a new file, but not the same file in vim

Tags: vim

For instance, how do I open a file I am going to use as the template for a file, but open it up as an unsaved buffer maybe? I don't know what methods I should use but I want to be able to save it right after as the file it's supposed to be.

My situation is for a jekyll blog where I have a basic post template and want to open that in vim from the command line so I can begin the post and then `:w *filename.md*`

Comment: What's wrong with just doing what you said? Or beforehand just copying the file?

Comment: I don't know how to open the file in vim so I can just easily save in another file. Without having to switch to editing a file like using `:e filename.md` after writing the new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `saveas` command. Assuming you have a template for posts named `template.md`, open `template.md`, make some edits, then instead of using `:w`, do `:sav newPost.md`.

No need to switch buffers: now your buffer will contain the file `newPost.md`, and `template.md` will remain unchanged on the filesystem.

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be something simple for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use the `:read` command or `:r` for short. e.g. `:r template.md` to read in the contents of `template.md` into the current buffer.

Pros:

- Can read in multiple templates
- Any buffer can be used, including unsaved or even a scratch buffer
- Do not have to worry about saving over the `template.md` file on accident
- Can be combined with the `:!` method to read in the output of a shell command. e.g. `:r!ls`
- Use a range with `:r` to read in a template at a specific point in the buffer. e.g. `:10r template.md` will read in `template.md` after line number 10.

Cons:

- May have an extra blank line. This can be easily deleted via `:0d_` or whatever your favorite method to delete a line.

Example workflow:

1. create buffer and read in template

   ```
   :new
   :r template.md|0d_
   ```
2. edit buffer
3. save buffer

   ```
   :w a-great-new-file.md
   ```

For more help see:

```
:h :r
:h :r!
:h :range
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ vim template.md
(edit)
:saveas filename.md
```

or

```
$ cp template.md filename.md && vim filename.md
```

or… I'm not sure I understand your problem.

The normal workflow is to open a template and "Save As…". In Vim and every other editor. What's wrong with that?

Or are you looking for a [templating](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=template&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) or [snippet-expansion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=snippet&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) plugin?

Comment: A template system would work for more complicated things, but I am looking for a more simple solution to the problem. Maybe that is what I need though.